# Can this text be misconstrued in a way that perverts its meaning?

Tags: phrases, semantics, linguistics

The sentence in question is the first sentence:

"Thank you for the opportunity of a 1 - 1 meeting"

"Sorry, I am busy. I cannot attend meet with you"

Without the 2nd sentence, indicating the participant's inability to attend a meeting, can the first sentence be interpreted to mean a meeting did occur, particularly due to the word "opportunity"?

Comment: Interpret it anyway you wish.

Comment: Hi, orangeshaker, and welcome! This seems to be more of a question of the order of arguments than of language. Look up "opportunity" in a dictionary, and then edit your question  to show exactly what part of its meaning is not clear. Cheers!

Comment: Also be aware that "I cannot attend meet with you " is incorrect.